# Multi-GPU model ( LSTM with Stateful ) on Keras is not working

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, multi-gpu

I am working on LSTM model with stateful using keras (Tensorflow backend); I cannot parallelize it on multi-GPU platform. [here is link to code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/training_utils.py). I am getting following error.

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [256,75,39] vs. [512,75,39]
>
> [[Node: training/cna/gradients/loss/concatenate_1_loss/mul_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs = BroadcastGradientArgs[T=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@loss/concatenate_1_loss/mul"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](training/cna/gradients/loss/concatenate_1_loss/mul_grad/Shape, training/cna/gradients/loss/concatenate_1_loss/mul_grad/Shape_1)]]
>
> [[Node: replica_1/sequential_1/dense_1/truediv/_473 = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:1", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_3032_replica_1/sequential_1/dense_1/truediv", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

I am using 2 GPU with batch size of 256. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please fix the link to your code?

Answer (score 2):

This error seems to happen simply because you're dividing an original batch with size 512 in two smaller batches with size 256.

Stateful layers require a fixed batch size (see the parameter `batch_shape` or `batch_input_shape` at the beginning of the model).

You may try to recreate the model changing the `batch_shape` (or `batch_input_shape`) to 256 (if it's currently 512). Or the other way around if I'm mistaken about the current value.

If you have already a trained model with weights you want to keep, you can create another model with the same type of layers and the same shapes, changing only the input shape. Then you can `newModel.set_weights(oldModel.get_weights())`

---

That said, I don't think it's safe to parallelize a stateful model. In stateful models, "batch2" is the sequel of "batch1". Both batches represent the "same" sequence, and the order is absolutely important. If batch2 gets processed before batch1, you will be inputting an inverted sequence and your model will learn it wrong.

Unless you find it explicitly stated by Keras documentation that you can safely parallelize a stateful model, you might benefit from checking carefully (after lots of attempts) if the parallelized model always gives the same result as the single GPU model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on [stateful_multi_gpu](https://github.com/visionscaper/stateful_multi_gpu), an experimental utility to build stateful RNN models for multi GPU training.

In contrary to [Daniel Möller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47200968/889617), I think you can explicitly state the order: what sub-batch is processed on which GPU and how the results are put back together.

I still need to test if it correctly trains on multiple GPUs, and if it can parallelise any arbitrary stateful model. Thus, I'm interested in anyones experience using this utility!